# How to allow CrossOrigin from all domains?

Tags: spring-boot, cors

Is there anyway to make this end point allow request from anywhere?

I've tried like but none of them worked.

> @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
>
>   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://*")

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3001")
@GetMapping(path="/transactions")
public @ResponseBody List<RealEstateTransaction> getTransactions() {
    return realEstateTransactionService.findTargets();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While working with cross domains, most of the time we tend to worry about what & where it went wrong. There are many factors including security, web components, sockets, etc to be handled at the server side before a request is processed. Many ways to implement the `CORS` in the Spring Boot application.

### 1. Annotation

By implementing `@CrossOrigin` like what you did in the `Main` class. Also can be done by adding `@CrossOrigin` to specific controllers/methods, if particular API should be accessed only from specific domain.

```java
@CrossOrigin("*") // to allow from all domains
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3001") // to allow from specific domain
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3001")
```

### 2. WebConfig

If Spring Application is MVC where the resources could be accessed. Simply add the CORS mappings by overriding `WebMvcConfigurer's` `addCorsMappings` function.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

### 3. SecurityConfig

When security is enabled in the application then CORS must be implementated in the `SecurityConfig`. Registering the CORS filter can be done in many ways. One is adding `UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource` to the http.cors() function. Another is to create `CustomCorsFilter` by extending the `CorsFilter`.

```java
public class CustomCorsFilter extends CorsFilter {

    public CustomCorsFilter() {
        super(configurationSource());
    }
    
    public static UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
    
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        corsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        
        return corsConfigurationSource;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] paths = {"/auth/**", "/env"};
        
        //http.cors().configurationSource(CustomCorsFilter.configurationSource()); // Option 1

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(paths)
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomCorsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); //option 2
}
```