# How to fix the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when connecting to a WebSocket?

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am working on a SockJS and WebSocket type of project and for the frontend I am using React and on the backend the spring's implementation of WebSockets. But I am getting a CORS error when I try to connect to my WebSocket.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/ws/info?t=1579096675068' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

In the Java project I have included this CORS configuration:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
     final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
     final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
     configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
     configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
     configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
     configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
     configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
     source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
     return source;
}
```

And as for the `configure` method on the `WebSecurity` class I have included this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
             .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
```

I add my socket endpoint like this:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}
```

On the frontend I connect to my WebSocket with a `connect` method:

```
connect = () => {
  const Stomp = require("stompjs");
  let SockJS = require("sockjs-client");
  SockJS = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
  stompClient = Stomp.over(SockJS);
  stompClient.connect({}, this.onConnected, this.onError);
};
```

I have tried setting the URL on the `registerStompEndpoints` method as `http://localhost:3000` explicitly, but to no effect. Also added a proxy on my `package.json` in the frontend to `http://localhost:8080/`, but it still gives the same error. Is there anything I need to do on my `corsConfigurationSource` to get this working?

UPDATE

When I do the following `configure` method it solves the WebSocket problem as it can connect to it, but I lose the ability to visit other routes of my application because it gives another error.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/ws").permitAll()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
             .and()
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
             .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

The other error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/me' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: I have an application like you have and working good. Have implemented the `cors` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58127178/7458887.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
              .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
              .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
              .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and().csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/auth/*", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/login", configuration);
        return source;
}
```

I ended up using this as my WebSecurity. To sum up I added `.antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()` on my `configure` method. So I permit all requests coming to my WebSocket endpoint and also explicitly registering CORS configuration on all my other routes except the `/ws` routes on the `corsConfigurationSource` method. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've spent hours looking for this.

Comment: You are a life saver. Now I don't hate programming!

Answer (score 0):

@David your angular code looks fine. I faced the same issue while connecting stomp webscoket from Angular8 to Sprint boot. After a lot of tweaks I ended up with a solution.
key point: In **HttpServletResponse** we need to set our domain (http://localhost:4200) in place of **"*"**.

```
@Configuration
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
    
    private final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200");
    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
        
        //Tweak here, pass your origin URL here
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "*");**
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        
        //Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implemented side update the **setAllowedOrigins** to your original domain URL

```
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```